# Firefox cause strange shadow artifacts (shadow cut in Firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox

Have some problem with firefox browser. I have some block with drop-shadow and when I try to hover link above it cause strange artifact (shadow cut). How can I prevent it? 1 pic - normal, 2 pic - when link hover (see above black curve)
[image: normal view]

[image: bad view]

Some css code for box with shadow

```
.game-video-content-video {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.55rem;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 4.16rem 8rem rgba(255, 139, 94, 0.65));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 4.16rem 8rem rgba(255, 139, 94, 0.65));
  overflow: visible;
  width: 58%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.game-video-content-video::before {
  content: '';
  height: 7%;
  width: 84%;
  background-image: url(./imgs/video-img-top.png);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  filter: none;
  top: 0.84%;
  right: 0.61%;
}

.game-video-content-video::after {
  content: '';
  height: 7.6%;
  width: 84%;
  background-image: url(./imgs/video-img-bot.png);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  filter: none;
  bottom: 0.84%;
  left: 0.37%;
}
```

And for links

```
.header-content-links__link {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 3.66rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.6s;
  -o-transition: color 0.6s;
  transition: color 0.6s;
}

.header-content-links__link:hover {
  color: rgb(255 139 94);
  /* text-shadow: 0 -0.3rem 1.9rem rgb(255 139 94); */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I need make transparent solid outline with size same as shadow or better more than shadow. That's it. Strangely thing on webkit browsers